# How to Select a Date from Date dropdown in Selenium

Tags: java, windows, selenium, selenium-webdriver, keyword

I'm trying to click and select date from calendar dropdown for birthdate input .It's in the twitter signup page and it's a popup.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@aria-label='Date of birth']/descendant::select[1]']")).click();
```

Tried this xpath but the element is not getting clicked. I'm new to this. How to do this?

[image: pop with date dropdown]

Comment: did you try `driver.executeScript("argument[0].click()", element)` ?

Comment: https://twitter.com/i/flow/signup

Comment: <select aria-invalid="false" aria-labelledby="SELECTOR_1_LABEL" class="r-30o5oe r-1niwhzg r-17gur6a r-1yadl64 r-18jsvk2 r-1loqt21 r-37j5jr r-1inkyih r-rjixqe r-crgep1 r-1wzrnnt r-1ny4l3l r-t60dpp r-xd6kpl r-1pn2ns4 r-ttdzmv" id="SELECTOR_1" data-testid=""><option disabled="" value="" class="r-14lw9ot"></option><option value="1" class="r-14lw9ot">January</option><option value="2" class="r-14lw9ot">February</option><option value="3" class="r-14lw9ot">March</option><option value="4" class="r-14lw9ot">April</option><option value="5" class="r-14lw9ot"> - after inspecting the element

Comment: Still cannot click the element,sadly.

Answer (score 0):

If the dropdown comes with "select tag" you can use Select Class as well as select options using `selectByValue` , `selectByIndex` and `selectByVisibleText`

```
Select month = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("SELECTOR_1_LABEL")));
month.selectByValue("1");
```

Comment: <select aria-invalid="false" aria-labelledby="SELECTOR_1_LABEL" class="r-30o5oe r-1niwhzg r-17gur6a r-1yadl64 r-18jsvk2 r-1loqt21 r-37j5jr r-1inkyih r-rjixqe r-crgep1 r-1wzrnnt r-1ny4l3l r-t60dpp r-xd6kpl r-1pn2ns4 r-ttdzmv" id="SELECTOR_1" data-testid=""><option disabled="" value="" class="r-14lw9ot"></option><option value="1" class="r-14lw9ot">January</option><option value="2" class="r-14lw9ot">February</option><option value="3" class="r-14lw9ot">March</option><option value="4" class="r-14lw9ot">April</option><option value="5" class="r-14lw9ot"> - after inspecting the element

Comment: Select month = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("SELECTOR_1"))); month.selectByValue("1");

Comment: Still cannot click the element, sadly.

Comment: @SheikhSamihaBinteSeraj substitute `SELECTOR_1_LABEL` with `SELECTOR_1`

Answer (score 0):

This is the complete code:

```
                WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://twitter.com/i/flow/signup");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'phone')]")).click();
    Select month = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("SELECTOR_1"))); 
    month.selectByValue("4");
    
    Select day = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("SELECTOR_2"))); 
    day.selectByValue("3");
    
    Select year = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("SELECTOR_3"))); 
    year.selectByValue("2023");
```